# How to scale a rounded UImageview?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, rounded-corners

I am scaling a rounded image view using an animation but the corner radius is not interpolated.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: time, 
animations: {() -> Void in

                       avatar.frame = CGRect(0, 0, avatarWidth, avatarWidth)
                       avatar.center = CGPoint(App.screenWidth / 2, centerY)
                       avatar.layer.cornerRadius = avatarWidth / 2
                    )
```

How can keep the rounded form during the whole animation?

Comment: set `this.avatar.Layer.maskToBounds = true`

Comment: correct your typo please (new, capital letters ... )

Comment: @Ocunidee It's Xamarin iOS

Comment: @dario Then please add a tag in order to help others avoid confusion

Comment: it looks like a java syntax. Some people switch from one language to another

Comment: @EricAya is it ok now?